# aggregating surefire reports in MultiModule project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I have multimodule maven project I want to get aggregated surefire reports . I tried below approach but I dont see aggregated surefire report generated. I could see report generated for individual modules.

I have added below plugin configuration in indvidual Modules (packaging jar)

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                    <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

And below in root level pom (packaging type pom)

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.plugin.surefire}</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                    <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Could some one please help where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mvn surefire-report:report -Daggregate=true`